# Is there a web app security auditing tool that produces reports showing what attack types were tested for?

Tags: security, security-testing

I want to generate a basic report from testing, I would like the testing to cover the OWASP top 10. I have looked at OWASP ZAP reporting but this just highlights any issues as opposed to saying XY and Z were tested for with no evidence of them occurring along with detailing the issues found.

This is not a question on how to test a web-application. The question is: Are there any tools that will generate reports specifying what was tested for along with vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

You can see what ZAP is testing for by selecting Analyse... / Scan Policy

We're also starting to document the rules under here https://code.google.com/p/zap-extensions/wiki/V2Extensions (look at the items under the tree on the left).

Note that no tool will be able to automatically test for all of the OWASP Top ten - you will really need to perform manual testing as well.

The ZAP reporting does need to be improved, and I'd like it to include a list of what was tested as well as what was found. ZAP is a community project - fancy working on this? ;)

Simon (ZAP project lead)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do perform manual testing I was just looking for a report I can use as a kinda of this is what we have tested passed and failed. I appreciate the work you guys are doing and use ZAP for the actual testing.